# Diophantine Equation on squares and cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all integer solutions to: $(a^2+b)(b^2+a)=(a-b)^3$

I've found some of the trivial cases, just finding difficulty proving the existence (or not existence) of others. Perhaps taking $mod5$ or something?

Comment: I don't think mod bashing will help.  For any modulus $m, b\equiv 0 \pmod m$ gives a solution, as does $a\equiv -1, b\equiv -1 \pmod m$.

Answer (score 2):

(EDITED)

$$(a^2+b)(b^2+a)-(a-b)^3 = b(a^2 b+3 a^2-3 a b+2 b^2+a)$$

The factor $b$ means $a=arbitrary, b=0$ are solutions.

The curve $a^2 b+3 a^2-3 a b+2 b^2+a=0$ has genus $0$ and rational parametrization
$$ a = {\frac {-2{s}^{2}}{ \left( 2\,s+1 \right)  \left( s+1 \right) }}, b = -{
\frac { \left( 4\,s+1 \right) s}{(2s+1)^2}}
$$
If $s = S/T$ with $S, T$ coprime integers, we get
$$ \eqalign{a &=  -1 + \frac{2T}{S+T} - \frac{T}{2S+T}\cr
            b &= -1 + \frac{3T}{2(2S+T)} - \frac{T^2}{2(2S+T)^2} \cr}$$
If $2S+T$ is divisible by any prime, this can't be an integer.  So the only possible cases are: 
 $2S+T=\pm 1$, which leads to the integer solutions $(a,b) = (-1,-1), (0,0), (8,-10), (9,-21)$.

EDIT: Oops, you could also have $2S+T = \pm 2$ if $T$ is divisible by $4$.
This leads to the additional solution $(9,-6)$.

Comment: (-5,2) , 
(-1,1),
(2,-5),
(4,11),
(5,7),
(7,5),
(11,4)

Comment: is that all solutions?

Comment: Oops: wrong sign, edited.

Comment: good god well done

Answer (score 1):

If $b\neq 0$ we have to solve a quadratic equation for $b$

$$a+3 a^2-3 a b+a^2 b+2 b^2=0$$

Since the discriminant must be a perfect square (a necessary condition), we get

$(-8+a) a (1+a)^2$ and therefore $a(a-8)$ must be a perfect square, so

$$a(a-8)=m^2$$

for some $m$. Rewriting this gives

$$(a-4-m)(a-4+m)=16$$

There are finitely many possible values for $a$, namely

$$a=-1,0,8,9$$

and

$$(a,b)=\{(-1,-1),(0,0),(8,-10),(9,-21),(9,-6)\}$$